# How to use global variable in pyspark function

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Firstly I have two variable at begining of code.

```
numericColumnNames = []
categoricalColumnsNames = [];
```

Then in main method  , I assign value to those values

```
def main():
  #clickRDD = sc.textFile("s3a://wer-display-ads/day_0_1000.csv"); 
  clickRDD = sc.textFile("data/day_0_1000.csv");
  numericColumnNames , categoricalColumnsNames = getColumnStructure();
```

Then When I want to use those variables in following function , Those variables are not updated and are empty

```
def dataToVectorForLinear(clickDF):
  print (categoricalColumnsNames) ## why this list is empty 
  clickDF = oneHotEncoding(clickDF,categoricalColumnsNames)
```

Unfortunetly I can't find the problem? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

Just re-initialize them inside the function 'global` keyword like this

```
def main():

    global numericColumnNames
    global categoricalColumnsNames     

    clickRDD = sc.textFile("data/day_0_1000.csv");
    numericColumnNames , categoricalColumnsNames = getColumnStructure();
```

Similarly

```
def dataToVectorForLinear(clickDF):

    global categoricalColumnsNames
    print (categoricalColumnsNames) 
    clickDF = oneHotEncoding(clickDF,categoricalColumnsNames)
```

Reference:

- [Global and local variables in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)